# Modeling firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Question about modeling in firebase

I have been getting into firebase lately, so I am still very new coming from a sql background.

I want to log the nrOfPlayers that are on a server of mine and save it on a db. I am logging every minute once with the amount of players that are online. To be able to put this in graphs, I want to have averages for every day and every month.

The model I've come up with is the one below with year/ being a collection and doc(year) being a document. The | below the document are all the fields and subcollections.

The average gets calculated at the end of the day and at the end of the month and is only updated once.

I was wondering if this is a good model, if there can be improvements or if there's better ways to do this. Thanks in advance for the help, the diagram below is my model.

Model:

```
Year/
 |Doc(year)
   |Month/
     |Doc(month)
       |AveragePlayers
       |Days/
         |Doc(day)
           |AveragePlayers
           |Minute/
             |Doc(minute)
             |NrOfPlayers
```

The given model is what I've come up with.
Im new to firestore and I am looking for some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If this model meets your use-case and the limits you have, then it is a good model. That's not being  facetious, but really how NoSQL databases are meant to be used: you model your data for the needs of your app, so if this meets those needs, then it's by definition a good model. :)

Some sources to learn more about this:

- [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

One thing to consider is if you really want to run the queries to calculate the new averages every minute, or if you want to use something like [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to run them in response to other [events that happen in your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). The latter might be beneficial (read: cheaper) if you may not get data updates all the time.